# input string not in correct format when selecting value from dropdown

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

my code throws error:

Input string not in correct format

code:

```
 protected void btnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RecievingDate", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FromMobileNo", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message", typeof(string)));
        dtRoom.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsComplaint", typeof(short)));
       // bool var = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //drw = dtRoom.NewRow();
            DropDownList IsValid = (DropDownList) GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlValidity");
            if (IsValid.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
                ManageRecievedMessage mngRecMsg = new ManageRecievedMessage();
                mngRecMsg.UpdateSmsComplaintValidity(ID, 1);

                //var = true;
                DataRow datarw = null;
                //dtRoom = new DataTable();
                datarw = dtRoom.NewRow();

                    datarw[0] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
                    datarw[1] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                    datarw[2] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
                    datarw[3] = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
                    datarw[4] =  Convert.ToInt16(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);

                dtRoom.Rows.Add(datarw);
```

it throws error at this line:

```
 datarw[4] =  Convert.ToInt16(GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
```

it should pass 1 to datarw 4 since i am selecting it from dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlValidity" runat="server">
                           <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="-Select-"></asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Valid"></asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Invalid"></asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Did you debug and see what is the actual value?

Comment: yes "1". 1 with quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because your `Value` is 1 but `Text` corresponding to it is "Valid". You are passing `Text`, which is not a number and so you get an error. Therefore, you should change your code to use the `Value` from the dropdown instead, like so:

```
datarw[4] =  Convert.ToInt16(IsValid.SelectedValue);
```